# Add values of keys and sort it by occurrence of the keys in a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I'm really new to Python and I'm stuck with the below problem that I need to solve.
I've a log file from Apache Log as below:

```
[01/Aug/1995:00:54:59 -0400] "GET /images/opf-logo.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 32511
[01/Aug/1995:00:55:04 -0400] "GET /images/ksclogosmall.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 3635
[01/Aug/1995:00:55:06 -0400] "GET /images/ksclogosmall.gif HTTP/1.0" 403 298
[01/Aug/1995:00:55:09 -0400] "GET /images/ksclogosmall.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 3635
[01/Aug/1995:00:55:18 -0400] "GET /images/opf-logo.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 32511
[01/Aug/1995:00:56:52 -0400] "GET /images/ksclogosmall.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 3635
```

I've to return the 10 most requested objects and their cumulative bytes transferred. I need to include only GET requests with Successful (HTTP 2xx) responses.

So the above log would result into:

```
/images/ksclogosmall.gif 10905
/images/opf-logo.gif 65022
```

So far I've the following code:

```
import re
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter
import itertools
import sys

log_file = "web.log"
pattern = re.compile(
      r'\[(?P<date>[^\[\]:]+):(?P<time>\d+:\d+:\d+) (?P<timezone>[\-+]?\d\d\d\d)\] '
      + r'"(?P<method>\w+) (?P<path>[\S]+) (?P<protocol>[^"]+)" (?P<status>\d+) (?P<bytes_xfd>-|\d+)')

dict_list = []

with open(log_file, "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if re.search("GET", line) and re.search(r'HTTP/[\d.]+"\s[2]\d{2}', line):
            try:
                log_line_data = pattern.match(line)
                path = log_line_data["path"]
                bytes_transferred = int(log_line_data["bytes_xfd"])
                dict_list.append({path: bytes_transferred})
            except:
                print("Unexpected Error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
                raise
    f.close()

print(dict_list)
```

This code prints the following list of dictionary.

```
[{'/images/opf-logo.gif': 32511}, 
{'/images/ksclogosmall.gif': 3635}, 
{'/images/ksclogosmall.gif': 3635}, 
{'/images/opf-logo.gif': 32511}, 
{'/images/ksclogosmall.gif': 3635}]
```

I don't know how to go about from here to get the result as:

```
/images/ksclogosmall.gif 10905
/images/opf-logo.gif 65022
```

This result is basically addition of values corresponding to similar keys sorted by number of times particular key occurred in a desc order.

Note: I tried using colllections.Counter with no avail, here I'd like to sort by the num of times the key occurred.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a collections.Counter and `update` it to add up the bytes transferred for each object:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
for d in dict_list:
    c.update(d)
occurrences=Counter([list(x.keys())[0] for x in dict_list])
sorted(c.items(), key=lambda x: occurrences[x[0]], reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
[('/images/ksclogosmall.gif', 10905), ('/images/opf-logo.gif', 65022)]
```

Comment: I have tried this but this is not what I need. I need to sort the list of dictionaries by the number of time a particular key occurred and at the same time add their values and the final output would be highest to lowest like: 
/images/ksclogosmall.gif 10905

/images/opf-logo.gif 65022

Comment: Still the same, it's sorted by the values. I want it sorted by the number of time a particular key occurred, so even though value corresponding to '/images/opf-logo.gif' key is 65022 as compared to '/images/ksclogosmall.gif' 's value that is 10905, it should still be on top as the key '/images/ksclogosmall.gif' occurred 3 times in the list of dictionaries compared the other one that occurred only twice.
Sorry about any confusion, I'm really stuck at this part for some time now.

Comment: OK, fixed for real this time!

Comment: Reducing a bunch of Counters with `operator.add` is inefficient, since it needs to copy Counters and scan for negative entries over and over again. It's faster to just construct an initial Counter and `update` it with each element of `dict_list`.

Answer (score 5):

First, a list of dictionaries doesn't really make sense for this type of data. Since each dictionary will only have one key-value pair, just construct a list of tuples (or a list of `namedtuples` if you want more readability).

```
tuple_list.append((path, bytes_transferred))
```

Now, getting the result that you want will be more straightforward. I'd personally use a `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

tracker = defaultdict(list)
for path, bytes_transferred in tuple_list:
    tracker[path].append(bytes_transferred)
# {'/images/ksclogosmall.gif': [3635, 3635, 3635], '/images/opf-logo.gif': [32511, 32511]}

print([(p, sum(b)) for p, b in sorted(tracker.items(), key=lambda i: -len(i[1]))])
# [('/images/ksclogosmall.gif', 10905), ('/images/opf-logo.gif', 65022)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop your dict and store the values in a new dict:

```
results = {}
for d in dict_list:
    for k, v in d.items():
        total = results.get(k, 0) # get previously stored value, 0 if none
        results[k] = total + v
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant solution, however it will work:

```
freq = {}
with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

    for line in lines:
        if 'GET' in line and 'HTTP' in line and '200' in line:
            path = line.split()[3]
            occur = int(line.split()[-1])
            freq[path] = freq.get(path, 0) + occur

frequency = {k: v for k, v in sorted(freq.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])}
```

So for your provided log snippet:

```
print(frequency)
>>> {'/images/ksclogosmall.gif': 10905, '/images/opf-logo.gif': 65022}
```

Comment: I actually have this output, what I need is a result sorted by number of times a key occurred in this list of dictionaries and their cumulative values. 

/images/ksclogosmall.gif 10905

/images/opf-logo.gif 65022

Comment: @leo_21 ahh sorry I misunderstood, and updated my answer.

Comment: No worries. I think it still gives the answer sorted by values, doesn't it? Sorry I'm not sure if I got the code right.  How can I sort by number of times a key occurred in a desc order and also add their cumulative value?

Comment: I see - I would update my answer but @Imran 's is a better approach, and what you're looking for I believe.

Comment: Yes, Thank you though for your input.

Answer (score 0):

another option, two lines

```
....
path = log_line_data["path"]
if [x for x in range(len(dict_list)) if path in dict_list[x].keys()]:
    continue
```

output

```
[{'/images/opf-logo.gif': 32511}, {'/images/ksclogosmall.gif': 3635}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to collapse

```
[{'/images/opf-logo.gif': 32511}, 
{'/images/ksclogosmall.gif': 3635}, 
{'/images/ksclogosmall.gif': 3635}, 
{'/images/opf-logo.gif': 32511}, 
{'/images/ksclogosmall.gif': 3635}]
```

Into a dictionary and total up the values with the same key:

1. Create a new, empty dictionary
2. Loop through each dictionary, check if the key exist in your new dictionary
3. If key (file path) does not exist, copy it over
4. If it exist, add the value

```

```
total = {}

for d in all:
    for k, v in d.items():
             if k in total:
                     total[k] += v
             else:
                     total[k] = v

print(total)
{'/images/opf-logo.gif': 65022, '/images/ksclogosmall.gif': 10905}
```